# AFNetworking code migration from 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, titanium-modules

I'm complete newbie to IOS development. I'm trying to rewrite this block of code with AFNetworking 2.0. How do i use response to get the status code and headers on the success or failure callback? This is in a titanium module for AFNetworking.

```
               AFJSONRequestOperation * operation = 
       [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request 
        success: ^ (NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, id JSON) {
             if (success) {
                 id response_body = JSON;
                 id status_code = [NSNull null];
                 id response_headers = [NSNull null];
                 id reason = [NSNull null];

                 if (!response_body)
                     response_body = [NSNull null];

                 if (response) {
                     status_code = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: response.statusCode];
                     response_headers = response.allHeaderFields;
                 }

                 [self _fireEventToListener: @"complete"
                     withObject: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(response_body, status_code, response_headers, reason) 
                     listener: success thisObject: nil
                 ];
                 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

             }
         }
         failure: ^ (NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, NSError * error, id JSON) {
             if (failed) {
                 id response_body = JSON;
                 id status_code = [NSNull null];
                 id response_headers = [NSNull null];
                 id reason = [NSNull null];

                 if (!response_body)
                     response_body = [NSNull null];

                 if (response) {
                     status_code = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: response.statusCode];
                     response_headers = response.allHeaderFields;
                 }

                 if (error && error.localizedDescription) {
                     reason = error.localizedDescription;
                 }

                 [self _fireEventToListener: @"complete"
                     withObject: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(response_body, status_code, response_headers, reason) 
                     listener: failed thisObject: nil
                 ];
                 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
             }
         }
     ];
```

Answer (score 0):

From a brief glance over the code, what it looks like you're slightly misunderstanding is the block syntax.

Right at the top of your `success` block  you have `if (success) {` code.
At no point in your code has there been a declaration of the **`success`** variable. The only variables that are passed into that success block are `request, response, JSON`.

You have the same thing happening in the `failure` block.

If you sort those out, you should see some progress.

Comment: Above is currently working code with afnetworking 1.3 version. Those success and failed variables are defined as kroll callbacks.Which is not in the above code.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to write the same code using AFHTTPRequestOperation since AFJSONRequestOperation is not available in afnetworking 2.0.AFJSONRequestOperation only allows operation and id as params.I need response to read status code and headers.@MultiColourPixel